# why is width: 100% working on this list item?

Tags: css

I'm creating a mobile nav and I have drop down menu on the charactors tab, with a back button on top made of simply a list item with text. With the back button though width 100% doesn't seem to be working I have check the dev tools and its seems like its should be working, I need it to be acting like the rest of the list items and its seem be be acting like its an inline element why?

the back a button only appears on widths 400px or less
https://jsfiddle.net/6e62ge46/11/

```
header nav{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
   // background-color: rgba(255,165,0,.8);
}
nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
}
.main-nav{
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: 600;
}
nav ul li{ 
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    background-color:rgba(255,165,0,.8);
    width: 100%;
}
.drop-menu-back{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

 nav a:visited, nav a,h1{
   color: white; 
}

.main-nav .current-page { 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
    /****drop down menu****/
.characters:hover {
            position: relative;
            border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
            }

     .drop-menu{
            position: absolute;
            visibility: hidden;
            display: block;
            top: 38px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            left: -2px;
            background-color: rgba(255,165,0,.8);
            border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.02);
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
            z-index: 1; 
            }
    .characters:hover .drop-menu{
             visibility: visible;
             opacity:1;
        }
  @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {

     .drop-menu{
          top:-50px;
          width: 100%;
      }
      .drop-menu-back{
          display: initial;
          width: 100%;
      }
    }
```

Comment: is this what you're trying to do? https://jsfiddle.net/6e62ge46/12/ `.drop-menu-back` at `width: 100%` will fill 100% of the parent, but the parent is `position: absolute` so it isn't 100% width of the page. To make `.back-menu-back` 100% width of the page, you need to make the parent 100%, too.

Comment: thanks but if you collapse the screen to 400px the back button starts ignoring width, for some reason

Comment: remove `display: initial` https://jsfiddle.net/6e62ge46/13/

Comment: ahh ok I see that works thanks but I dont understand why its wokring. Wouldnt initial set it back to its default display which is display list-item and itsn't that similar to a block element, which has setable width and height?

Comment: `initial` *"I don't think that word means what you think it means!"* it's a weird property and doesn't "revert" an element back to what it was. Read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial

Comment: @MichaelCoker You should have posted that as an answer.